# Разработка программы 1 курса введение в программную инженерию

Tags: c

Объясните сортировку массива методом Бабушкина, что за метод?

Comment: Никто не будет делать за вас домашнее задание. Задайте конкретный вопрос о том что у вас не получилось при попытке его выполнить.

Comment: Я не понимаю сам этот метод Бабушкина

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/articles/198114/#comment_6870028 вот в этом комментарии описан метод подбора числа Бабушкина, а сам метод в статье.